# jquery removeclass not working on live elements in html

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have a jquery script  that get a string and make `li` element for each letter, I have a for loop for selecting each letter from last to first and want to remove a class from these `li`'s in for loop by selecting them using `.eq()`, but it only affect on last element and other elements class not remove.
my code is:

```
var str = this.html(),
    container = this;

container.after('<ul class="letters-wrapper"></ul>').hide();

for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++){
    $('.letters-wrapper').append('<li class="each-letter dropIn stay-up">'+ str[i] +'</li>');
    if(str[i] == " "){
        $('.letters-wrapper').append('<li class="each-letter dropIn stay-up">'+ '&nbsp;' +'</li>');
    }
}
for(var i = $('.each-letter').length-1; i>=0; i--){
    var j = ($('.each-letter').length-1) - i;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.each-letter.dropIn').eq(i).removeClass('stay-up');
        }, j*100);
    } 
}
```

Comment: why don't you just create the li without the class? It looks like you are trying to create an animation, in that case use jQuery animate and toggleClass.

Comment: Why you want to use `setTimeout` function? You have such specific requirement? `setTimeout` is causing the problem in your case.

Comment: i think its about using variable in .eq(i), because when i use direct index number it affects on the element, for example .eq(8), it works on .each-letter by index(8)

Comment: i want to add some css animation in specific timeout, like dropping down elements

Comment: If you remove `setTimeout` function the your code will run properly.

Comment: i removed setTimeout and it works, but i need to set timeout, what can i do?

Comment: i found a way, i used foreach instead of for:
$('.each-letter').each(function(i){
    var j = $('.each-letter').length - i;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.each-letter.dropIn').eq(j).removeClass('stay-top');
    }, i*100);
});

Comment: Check whether it removes `stay-top` class from the `1st element`. I am sure it doesn't with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work with `setTimeout` try this code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LjqdLt9b/)

```
var str = this.html(),
container = this;

container.after('<ul class="letters-wrapper"></ul>').hide();

for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++){
    $('.letters-wrapper').append('<li class="each-letter dropIn stay-up">'+ str[i] +'</li>');
    if(str[i] == " "){
        $('.letters-wrapper').append('<li class="each-letter dropIn stay-up">'+ '&nbsp;' +'</li>');
    }
}

for(var i = $('.each-letter').length-1; i>=0; i--){
    var j = ($('.each-letter').length-1) - i;
    doSetTimeout(i);
} 
function doSetTimeout(i) {
  var j = ($('.each-letter').length-1) - i;
  setTimeout(function() { 
      $('.each-letter.dropIn:eq('+i+')').removeClass('stay-up'); 
  }, j*200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to use set timeout for my code:

```
$('.each-letter').each(function(i){
    var j = $('.each-letter').length - i;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.each-letter.dropIn').eq(j).removeClass('stay-top');
    }, i*100);
});
```

Comment: Check whether it removes `stay-top` class from the `1st element`. I am sure it doesn't with this code.

Answer (score -1):

check two things. first put a console.log before defining var j in second loop and check how many times this will log in console. if it logs only one time means your condition in for is wrong and if it logs as many as your li count, problem is in your setTimeout. for loop will render j and puts last j value in timeout

Comment: this can go in comment. Not in answer.

Comment: i checked both i and j are looping correctly, it's about my timeout

Answer (score -3):

Check for the jquery conflicts. That will be the problem if its not working on live. replace $ by jQuery and check

Comment: this is a comment not  an answer